Why is EasyOCR returning a single digit when processing a block of text?
I am running the code below on a PDF, and in most cases the text was detected successfully and then read reasonably by EasyOCR. But I also encountered cases where the text predicted was entirely off - specifically, the entire block would be returned as single number that looks nothing like any of the characters in the block of text.
Code used:
# v1
import os
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
import json
import cv2
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import pdf2image
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def process_pdfs(filenames, visualize=True):
    """
    Process PDF files using EasyOCR with advanced preprocessing and confidence scoring.
    
    Args:
        filenames (list): List of PDF file paths to process
        visualize (bool): Whether to generate visualization images
    
    Returns:
        list: Processed data with text extraction details
    """
    # Suppress warnings to keep output clean
    warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning)
    
    # Initialize EasyOCR reader for English with GPU
    reader = easyocr.Reader(
        ['en'], 
        gpu=True,  # Use GPU if available
        download_enabled=True,  # Automatically download models if not present
        detector=True,
        recognizer=True
    )
    
    processed_data = []
    
    for filename in filenames:
        # Convert PDF to images with high DPI for better OCR
        images = pdf2image.convert_from_path(
            filename, 
            dpi=300,  # High resolution for better text recognition
            poppler_path=r"C:\poppler\Release-24.07.0-0\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin"
        )
        
        for page_num, image in enumerate(images):
            # Convert PIL Image to numpy array
            img_np = np.array(image)
            
            # Preprocessing steps
            # preprocessed_img = preprocess_image(img_np)
            
            # Recognize text with confidence
            results = reader.readtext(
                img_np, 
                decoder='wordbeamsearch',  # More advanced decoding
                beamWidth=5,
                contrast_ths=0.1,          # Handle low contrast text
                adjust_contrast=0.5,
                rotation_info=[0, 90, 180, 270]  # Check all possible text orientations
            )
            
            # Prepare page results
            page_results = {
                'filename': filename,
                'page_number': page_num + 1,
                'text_blocks': []
            }
            
            # If visualization is enabled, annotate the image
            if visualize:
                img_with_annotations = annotate_image_with_ocr_results(img_np, results)
                output_filename = f"{os.path.splitext(filename)[0]}_page_{page_num+1}_annotated.png"
                cv2.imwrite(output_filename, cv2.cvtColor(img_with_annotations, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
            
            for detection in results:
                # Unpack result: (bounding_box, text, confidence)
                bbox, text, confidence = detection
                
                page_results['text_blocks'].append({
                    'bounding_box': bbox,
                    'text': text,
                    'confidence': float(confidence)
                })
            
            processed_data.append(page_results)
    
    return processed_data

def annotate_image_with_ocr_results(image, ocr_results):
    """
    Annotate image with OCR bounding boxes and text.
    
    Args:
        image (numpy.ndarray): Input image
        ocr_results (list): OCR detection results
    
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: Annotated image
    """
    # Create a copy of the image to draw on
    annotated_image = image.copy()
    
    for (bbox, text, confidence) in ocr_results:
        # Convert bounding box to integer coordinates
        bbox = np.array(bbox, dtype=np.int32)
        
        # Determine color based on confidence
        if confidence > 0.9:
            color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green for high confidence
        elif confidence > 0.7:
            color = (0, 255, 255)  # Yellow for medium confidence
        else:
            color = (0, 0, 255)  # Red for low confidence
        
        # Draw bounding box
        cv2.polylines(annotated_image, [bbox], isClosed=True, color=color, thickness=2)
        
        # Prepare text label
        label = f"{text} ({confidence*100:.1f}%)"
        
        # Determine text position (top-left of bounding box)
        text_pos = tuple(bbox[0])
        
        # Add text above the bounding box
        cv2.putText(
            annotated_image, 
            label, 
            (text_pos[0], text_pos[1] - 10),  # Slightly above the box
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 
            0.5,  # Font scale
            color, 
            1  # Thickness
        )
    
    return annotated_image

def preprocess_image(image):
    """
    Advanced image preprocessing for OCR.
    
    Args:
        image (numpy.ndarray): Input image
    
    Returns:
        numpy.ndarray: Preprocessed image
    """
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    
    # Adaptive thresholding for smooth transition
    adaptive_thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        gray, 
        255, 
        cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 
        11, 
        2
    )
    
    # Noise reduction using bilateral filter
    denoised = cv2.bilateralFilter(adaptive_thresh, 9, 75, 75)
    
    # Deskew using OpenCV moments method
    coords = np.column_stack(np.where(denoised > 0))
    angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
    
    # Correct rotation angle
    if angle < -45:
        angle = -(90 + angle)
    else:
        angle = -angle
    
    # Rotation matrix
    (h, w) = denoised.shape[:2]
    center = (w // 2, h // 2)
    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(denoised, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    
    return rotated

def save_results_to_json(processed_data, output_file='ocr_results.json'):
    """
    Save processed data to a JSON file, converting NumPy arrays to lists.
    
    Args:
        processed_data (list): Processed OCR results
        output_file (str): Path to output JSON file
    """
    def convert_numpy_to_list(obj):
        """
        Recursively convert NumPy arrays to lists and NumPy types to standard Python types.
        """
        if isinstance(obj, np.ndarray):
            return obj.tolist()
        elif isinstance(obj, np.int32):
            return int(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, np.float32):
            return float(obj)
        elif isinstance(obj, dict):
            return {k: convert_numpy_to_list(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            return [convert_numpy_to_list(v) for v in obj]
        return obj
    
    # Convert the processed data to a JSON-serializable format
    serializable_data = convert_numpy_to_list(processed_data)
    
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        json.dump(serializable_data, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

Sample fail cases:Processed as single-digit cases
I actually tried reducing the text reading lower threshold from the default of 0.4 to 0.2 and the blocks were returning characters - albeit inaccurately, so I am wondering if the single-digit returns are some form of placeholder for the cases where blocks of text cannot be deciphered with sufficient confidence? Could not find anything specific about such a behaviour in the docs https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR
Processed as text cases
